# Scala: What's the best way to filter and flatten Seq[Option[A]]

Tags: scala, collections, option-type

Let's say I have a `val allStrs: Seq[Option[String]] = Seq(Some("A"),  Some("B"), None)`

And would like to have a result like this: `Seq("A", "B")`, what's the most elegant/Scala way to do this?

I have one way is `allStrs.filter(_.isDefined).flatten`, is it the best way?

Comment: You don't need `filter`, just `allStrs.flatten`

Comment: Then it will also filter the None?

Comment: I personally prefer to use `collect` like: `val result = allStrs.collect { case Some(str) => str }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this will work:

```
val allStrs: Seq[Option[String]] = ???
val s: Seq[String] = allStrs.flatten
```

The `flatten` operation operates on a sequence of containers. It takes the elements out of each of the individual containers and creates a single sequence containing all those elements.

`Option` behaves a lot like like a container with 0 or 1 elements. So `flatten` on a sequence of `Option`s will extract the values from those `Option`s. It removes all `None` values in the sequence and extracts the contents  of all the `Some` values.